# Why Kendo DatePicker is not formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a **ASP.NET MVC Project**. My `kendoDatePicker` was working great before I added an event of a `checkBox`. This event consist in changing the `min` date to **2015** or **2016** depending of `checkBox` state

This is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
     .Name("TxBxFechaInicial")
     .Value(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())
     .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
     .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:150px"})
)
```

Everything is okay here (today is January 18th):

[image]

```
 $('#chk2015').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#TxBxFechaInicial").kendoDatePicker({
            format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
            value: new Date(2015, 0, 1),
            min: new Date(2015, 0, 1),
        });
    } else {
        $("#TxBxFechaInicial").kendoDatePicker({
            format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
            value: new Date(2016, 0, 1),
            min: new Date(2016, 0, 1),
        });
    }
});
```

But after changing the `min` date it looks like this, ignoring the format, even if I manually change the date with the calendar.

[image]

The culture is already declared in the `$(document).ready(function ()` with `kendo.culture("es-MX");` also in **Web.config** with

```
<system.web>
   <globalization culture="es" uiCulture="es-MX" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Have you included kendo.culture.es-MX.min.js javascript file in your website?

Comment: Well, that worked. Thanks @EdinMahmutovic